# Array always starts at one, empty zero

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, json

I'm trying to read my MySQL data and put it as JSON. But I just want a single JSON Object, it tries giving me a JSONArray, but that array is empty.

This is what it gives me, top is JSON, bottom is simple array.

```
[
     [],
    {
        "id": "1",
        "description": null,
        "copyright": "&#169; Ian Ransley, flickr.com\/CC BY 2.0"
    }
]

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [description] => 
            [copyright] => &#169; Ian Ransley, flickr.com/CC BY 2.0
        )

)
```

As you can see, the zero index is empty for some reason, and right before my object starts there is an opening and closing bracket ([]), which makes my android app recognize that as an array instead of object.

here's my php code:

```
 <?php
 header('Content-type: text/plain');

 $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "bananatime", "Yoyobanana", "bananatime")
            or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));
 if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM bananas WHERE id = '".$_GET['id']."' ORDER BY id";
 }else{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM bananas ORDER BY id";
 }
 $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " .mysqli_error($connection));

 $array[] = array();
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
     {
         array_push($array, $row);
     }
 array_values($array);
 echo json_encode($array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
 echo "\n\n";
 print_r($array);

 mysqli_close($connection);
 ?>
```

Comment: How are we supposed to know what you did wrong if you don't post your code?

Comment: Damn, sorry, I'll edit my post in a second,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change `$array[] = array();` to `$array = array();`

Comment: It would be beneficial to explain what the difference is

Comment: The original syntax both declares the `$array` variable and concurrently appends `array()` to it, resulting in `$array = array(array())`. When you later use `array_push()` on it, you are appending `$row`, resulting the undesired output.

Answer (score 0):

array_push() was the problem. I had to use $array = $row;

Comment: that will fail if you have more than one row, when `$_GET['id']` is not set

Comment: it does not fail, it just shows the last object in line, which is just fine for me right now.

Comment: @TemporaryName Then it's pointless for you to actually get all the rows if you only show the last

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen yes, maybe, I don't really understand how to fetch only one object. This is just a workaround for me to use the MySQL database with my app, as long as it works it's fine for me.